# Unable to bind dynamic Column data to Jquery Gijgo Grid

Tags: jquery, dynamic, binding, grid

I am trying to bind the dynamic Column data to Jquery Gijgo grid and it does not display the grid data

I have constructed the dynamic string and trying to assign the same to columns param of Grid.

```
var columnData = "{ field: 'Series'}, ";
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/GetGridData",
        contentType: "application/json",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data[0], function (k, v) {
                if (k != 'Series') {
                    columnData = columnData + "{ field: '" + k + "', editor: true},";
                }
            });
            columnData = columnData.substring(0, columnData.length - 1);
            columnData = "[ " + columnData + " ]";

            $('#Grid').grid({
                dataSource: data,
                columns: columnData
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

I have tried to bind the columnData value from Console directly and it works.
example: 
columns: [{ field: 'Series' }, { field: '03/29/19', editor: true }, { field: '03/30/19', editor: true }, { field: '03/31/19', editor: true }, { field: '03/29/191', editor: true }]

Answer (score 0):

You need in your Ajax call in success part call this after setting datasource:

```
$('#Grid').grid().render(data);
```

Or after you have set your dataSource in grid:

```
$('#Grid').grid().reload();
```